# How to check if column 1 has two different values for column 2

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, duplicates

I am trying to make a INSERT by UNIQUE and I am getting stuck, What I want too know is how I would do is make it so Column A is ALWAYS UNIQUE unless Column C has two different values and then it will insert into the database a second row for Column A where Column C is different.

```
a|b|c
-----
1|2|3
2|4|5
1|6|7
```

So I am currently using this sql table

```
CREATE TABLE `Player` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`playername` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`SteamID` varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`position` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`lastlogin` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`approved` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

With this query

```
$sql1= "INSERT IGNORE INTO Player (playername, SteamID, position, lastlogin, approved) VALUES ('$name', '$id', '$position', '$lastlogin', '$approve')";
```

It inserts the way I want so there is only 1 of each SteamID but it also will not insert if the same SteamID has two values for position.

EDIT:

What I have is a xml file I load up and insert data into the database based on the data in the xml file, What I need is below.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("players.xml");
foreach($xml->children() as $player)
{
    $id = $player->attributes()->id;
    $profile = new SteamProfile($id);
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($profile->getUsername());
    $lastlogin = $player->attributes()->lastlogin;
    $position = $player->lpblock->attributes()->pos;
    $sql1= "INSERT IGNORE INTO Player (playername, SteamID, position, lastlogin, approved) VALUES ('$name', '$id', '$position', '$lastlogin', '$approve')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql1,$connection))
    {
            die('Insert Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

so the xml file gets read and then the data in the file gets inserted into the database. sometimes the xml file would contain

```
<player id="76561197961716203" lastlogin="8/22/2014 10:49:28 PM">
        <acl id="76561197961543041"/>
        <acl id="76561197988417990"/>
        <lpblock pos="273,93,-102"/>
        <lpblock pos="1322,62,-1711"/>
    </player>
```

at which point I would need a second row created for the second `<lpblock pos=`

So its currently inserting

|60|SwordFish |76561197961716203|273,93,-102|8/22/2014 10:49:28 PM|Yes|2014-08-24 15:28:16|

and it should be inserting

|60|SwordFish |76561197961716203|273,93,-102|8/22/2014 10:49:28 PM|Yes|2014-08-24 15:28:16|
|61|SwordFish |76561197961716203|1322,62,-1711|8/22/2014 10:49:28 PM|Yes|2014-08-24 15:28:16|

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you can set a UNIQUE restraint on a combination of columns, in your case `SteamID` and `position`:

```
CREATE TABLE `Player` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`playername` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`SteamID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`position` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`lastlogin` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`approved` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_combination_of_two_fields` (`SteamID`,`position`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: My code pulls data from a XML file it then takes that data and inserts it in a database. I want it to not insert duplicates, in other words if I refresh my page I don't want it to keep inserting the same data over and over. But I DO want a duplicate if and only if the position column has a duplicate for SteamID. So if SteamID has two of position it will insert both.

Comment: @Lordicon Then you can use the `UNIQUE` restraint on multiple columns like I have done.

Comment: This didn't help me so maybe its something else going on so I updated my original question with more information.

Comment: @Lordicon It would seem my answer satisfies the database side, but you would need to loop over the `lpblock` childs to insert different positions.

Comment: Problem I have is a lot of the lpblock pos are blank with no data so it would grab that as well wouldn't it? I have some xml like this `<player id="76561197994621715" lastlogin="8/20/2014 11:26:09 PM">
 </player>`

Comment: I posted a answer with another question if you could give me ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you help Jeroen I did this and its working.

```
foreach($player->children() as $lpblock) 
    {
        $position = $lpblock->attributes()->pos;
        if(!empty($position))
        {
            $sql1= "INSERT IGNORE INTO Player (playername, SteamID, position, lastlogin, approved) VALUES ('$name', '$id', '$position', '$lastlogin', '$approve')";
            if (!mysql_query($sql1,$connection))
            {
                die('Insert Error: ' . mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
```

However I would like all of the SteamID's inserted and not just the ones with a $position set. When I take this out and try it adds the correct rows but also adds another row with a blank $position as if there is a SteamID that's blank when there is none.

```
if(!empty($position)){

    }
```

Comment: @jeroen Can you help with this?